# Using JSoup to clean Scala Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, jsoup, user-defined-functions

I have a Scala Spark DataFrame:

```
id, content
1, "<p>Some paragraph</p>"
2, "<p><li>Some listings</li></p>"
...
```

Basically, "content" column contains textual data with html and I would like to strip it. Currently, I'm using a UDF using the Jsoup library (not actual implementation code, but you get the idea):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
Jsoup.parse(content).text()
```

It gets the job done but it's not performant and I've read that UDF is slow, is there any way I can apply the function to the column that optimises concurrency to get the results?

Ideal output:

```
id, clean_content
1, "Some paragraph"
2, "Some listings"
...
```

Comment: Unless you experience real latency issues in close-to-realtime pipeline, just use UDF and move on. There huge performance killers in Spark, like `joins`, window functions, `collect_list`, `f(distinct col)` (for different `f`), `coalesce(1)` / `repartition(1) `mapGroups`, good old `groupByKey` (with all the homegrown variants) and so on  - these are the one you should worry about. Sweating over constant overhead here and there (especially if not working in a guest language) doesn't make sense. Just consider that Spark and established packages use UDFs heavily in many places :)

Comment: And if you just want to strip tags, `cleanxml` from https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp, might do the trick (and yes, it is yet another UDF).